# Bypassing VPN detecting websites and services?

Tags: vpn

Currently one of the websites I'm visiting blocks all VPN traffic from services like privateinternetaccess, torguard, and other vpn providers. How can one prevent VPN detection without exposing their IP address?

The service I'm trying to use is banned in my country, which is why I need to use a VPN, but it seems that this service now has banned all VPNs too. What are some solutions and how can they even detect that I'm coming from a VPN?

Comment: You might could setup an OpenVPN server on a cheap VPS from another country and then connect to that. They're probably detecting if the IP address you're using is on an IP range that are known to be VPN IP addresses for those particular services.

Answer (score 2):

Lets handle this question as two different:

> How can they even detect that I'm coming from a VPN?

It's not that hard to look if someone is coming from a VPN provider. Most of them are using static IP addresses. There are lists of their exit gateways. They block this IP and no one can come through. Even if they don't use such type of an address they just need to make an automatic DNS reverse lookup and see that this have to be a VPN provider.

If this also don't work, you can look into the round trip time of a tcp ack. If it lasts too long you are able to take this as an indicator.

> What are some solutions?

That's a bit tricky. If you are into VPN's I would suggest to rent a Server in a country where the Website is allowed. After that you should set an OpenVPN Server up. Maybe [this](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO) Tutorial helps you. Connect to your own server and surf on this site.

Comment: I don't think you can determine if an IP address is running a VPN or not based only upon if lots of users are connecting from the same IP address. This doesn't make much sense. Consider cellular networks, as well as corporate networks. I highly doubt this is how they discern which of their traffic is coming from a VPN. Also, you specifically mentioned "It's not hard to look if someone is coming from a Open VPN provider", then continued to explain using the above approach. I don't think this can be considered factual or good enough for an answer since it's mostly assumptions. - my reason for dv

Comment: Actually this is best practise of big companies. They are using lists of IP´s and there amount of user they are coming from them. If they have a clearly suspicious behavior like creating accounts or do other stuff they know it's from an VPN and no residental location.
Why do you think it won't work to set up an OpenVPN Service on a server outside the country? And why should this be an assumtion?

Comment: Suspicious behavior is not connecting, though. What you're referring to are called "IP Blacklists" and the listed addresses contained in them are hardly determined by volume of connections, unless they're pointless connections like Ping of Death

Comment: As for your question to me about why I think it won't work; I never said that I don't think it will work. I think the second bit of your response was accurate, but I'm pointing out that the first, larger portion wasn't necessary and by most it's inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

## One thing you could try

*I have to make a few assumptions to answer this question, considering I do not know what measures the website has in place to avoid access through a VPN. As a result, this method may or may not work.*

If you are able to find a cheap VPS host, you could setup your own VPN on that VPS. In case you didnt know; a **VPS is a Virtual Private Server** and a **VPN is a Virtual Private Network**. I suggest searching for the best way to go about setting up the server once you've got a VPS to work with or following one of the tutorials I've linked below. Usually depending on how much you spend, it may not be the fastest, but it could quite possibly get the job done. Make sure that the IP address the server you rent is labeled to a country that is allowed to access the website you're attempting to connect to.

As a side note, I recommend using the **SoftEther VPN Server software for a Windows based VPS**, but if you use a **Linux based VPS, I suggest using OpenVPN Server**. There are some excellent youtube tutorials for setting these up. I provided one that I found for each of them in links below.

[Softether VPN Server Software Setup Tutorial (For Windows VPS)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VbvRhPqNCsk)

[OpenVPN Server Software Setup Tutorial (For Linux VPS)](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-linux-14-04-or-16-04-lts/)